# How to create a "New xxx" popup?

Tags: popup, field, atk4

I have a Grid object and added a **[ (+) New Client ]** button which I'd like to open a popup form to create the new client with a couple fields.

I've looked at the code examples in the website but haven't found how to do it (sorry if I've missed something).

This is the current page code:

```
function page_clients_listing($p){

    $g = $p->add('Grid');
    $g->addColumn('text','first_name');
    $g->addColumn('text','last_name');
    $g->addColumn('inline','telephone');
    $g->addColumn('expander','comments');
    $g->setSource('client');

    $g->addButton('With Icon')->set('Add New Client')->setIcon('Plus');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create a popup or a dialog. Dialog is based on jQuery UI dialog implementation. Popups are likely to be blocked and are harder to control.

This is actually working for any object (you can apply to view, button, image, icon, etc), but I'll use button).

```
$b=$g->addButton('Add New Client')->setIcon('Plus');

$b->js('click')->univ()->frameURL($title,$url);
// OR
$b->js('click')->univ()->dialogURL($title,$url);
```

$url would most likely be returned by api->getDestinationURL(). The other page would be loaded and scripts on that page will be evaluated. Let's say you are on other page and now need to close the window.

```
$result = $this->addButton('Close')->js('click')->univ()->closeDialog();
```

closeDialog() returns a jQuery chain object pointing to a view which originally opened the frame. As a result if you do $result->hide(); then after dialog is closed, the original button ('add new client') will also be hidden.

Here is example to show some additional things you can do with frames, reloading and custom event handlers:

http://agiletoolkit.org/example/refresh1